# Auto double new lines for textarea?

Tags: jquery, regex

I'd like to have it so when users press the enter key to make a line break, it instead produces double breaks: `\n\n`.

Is there a way to do this through jQuery & Regex?

Preferably when pasting text as well, it would transform single breaks to double breaks.

The end result would be a textarea where its practically impossible to enter one single new line versus two.

Comment: so, you want to make a line break or `\n\n`?

Comment: @ling.s that would be `\n\n`

Answer (score 2):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/psXn5/

```
// main code
function replaceLineBreak() {
    // save caret position
    var caret = $(this).caret();
        text = $(this).val();

    // adjust caret position
    var linebreak = text.match(/\n/g);
    if (linebreak != null) {
        caret += linebreak.length * 3
    }

    $(this).val( text.replace(/\n/g, "\\n\\n") );

    // restore caret position
    $(this).caret(caret);
}

// update on change
$('textarea').change(replaceLineBreak);

// update on key up
$('textarea').keyup(replaceLineBreak);
```

Comment: Thanks Wing so much, this almost worked however, it prints `\n\n` instead of real new lines for some reason. (I'm on Windows)

Comment: @Jeff It's not my answer but try changing `text.replace(/\n/g, "\\n\\n")`, to `text.replace(/\n/g, "\n\n")`

Comment: Oh, I think I am misunderstanding =3=.
If so, I think it is impossible to live update. It will replace every type you press a key.
Or could it be only max 2 line break together ?

Comment: I actually did, and the first try works great, next time i enter another new line it adds 4, and 8, and 16 lines.

Comment: I think if I can only match one single `\n` in a row and replace it with double `\n`'s, that'd work like a charm, but I have no idea how to do it with regexp :(

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't clearly understood what you are looking for. Here is the example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SYwpy/199/) for adding two breaks

```
$('#textareaid').keyup(function() {
   $('#divid').html($(this).val().replace(/\n/g,'<br/><br/>')); 
});
```

If you want to add `\n\n` on enter key press try this

```
$('#textareaid').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var s = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(s+"\n\n");
    }
});​
```

Comment: For some reason `/\n/g` matches already existant double new lines and results in lots of `\n` because of that, how can i make it match one `\n` in a row only?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#textbox').keyup(function (e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $("#textbox").append("\n\n");
}
});
```

It checks to see if your clicked enter, then it will add two \n at the end of the text box. Given your textarea is called textbox.